# Modal backdrop with a hole

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out a way in which I can create a transparent modal backdrop but show some parts off the background in a round radius. Something like this. [image]

My mind says it can be possible with Canvas tag. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to calculate size of highlighted parts dynamically?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I have to. That is not an issue. The issue is how to glance through a transparent div.

Comment: A SVG mask is what you want. Do you need demo?

Comment: There is [this plugin](http://jwarby.github.io/jquery-pagewalkthrough/), not sure if it does circles out of the box but its along the lines of what you're trying to do

Comment: a transparent div with border-radius 50% and a huge box-shadow

Answer (score 2):

I bet the [enjoyhint jQuery plugin](https://github.com/xbsoftware/enjoyhint) is exactly what you are looking for.

They have a [demo here](http://xbsoftware.github.io/enjoyhint/), the third step in is a circle like:

[image]

Comment: Although I'm definitely not bringing jQuery into my project, this is EXACTLY the experience I was looking to implement. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I'm going to see if I can create a vanilla JS version of this so I don't have to use jQ.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with multiple elements, using an SVG or image for the hole. Only the corners of the image would be filled in.

[image]

Or you could make a big SVG that would extend far beyond the edges of the window. Browsers probably clip the rendered area to the window, so it might not perform too badly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for masks? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Browser support doesn't look to be great